# why is my page reloading when re rendering a component

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, axios, use-effect

I am doing a api call and then another for each of the object received in the first request.

I have a load more button at the end of my page to get more data added on the page.

Each time the button is clicked the data is fetched but the page reloads and then makes the UI go back to the top of the page instead of just appending the new data.

Not sure what would force the page to reload?

This is my useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //this if/else statement is to find out if the page has been reloaded
    if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
      console.log("This page is reloaded");
    } else {
      console.log("This page is not reloaded");
    }
    setLoading(true);
    let cancel;
    axios
      .get(currentPageUrl, {
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
      }).then((res) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setNextpageUrl(res.data.next);
        setPokemons([...pokemons, ...res.data.results])
      
      }).catch((e) => {
        setErr(true)
      })
  }, [currentPageUrl]);
```

this is the function that would change the `currentPageUrl` :

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    setCurrentPageUrl(nextPageUrl);
  }
```

Comment: This... doesn't look like a side effect at all, you sure you don't want to use a regular class instead of a function so you can do all these things in their own functions instead of cramming everything inside render?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans what do you mean it doesn't look like a side effect?

Comment: If possible, would you be able to add more code or better would be CodePen/Sandbox example?

Comment: sure, i'll get on it now @AbhijeetAbnave

Comment: @AbhijeetAbnave https://codesandbox.io/s/pokemon-sandbox-2vrr9

Comment: @GDelsaux that's what `useEffect` is for: it's code that runs [as a side effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) of your actual updates, after render finishes. It is intended for code that "leaves" React: nothing it does should do anything to your component or other react-related code as a result. If you need to always run code that ends in state updates, based on "whatever the current values are", use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) instead. (Or use `class extends React.Component` code with a `componentDidUpdate` function)

Comment: It should never do that. `useEffect` kicks in _after_ render completes, and should in no way trigger a rerender. Whatever code it runs should not affect your component. It _can_, because of how JS scoping works, but as per the React docs and tutorials that's the proverbial "you're doing it wrong".

Comment: (as for how to do it "right", it's often worth (re)reading the entire hooks chapter over on https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html to re-examine whether you're still using React the way it's intended to be used, because using the right approach first may immediately solve any bugs that are a(n) (indirect) result of using the wrong approach)

Comment: Thank you for redirecting to the entire React documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, the solution was simply to create a function that would handle the logic then put it inside the use effect.

```
const request = () => {
  if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
    console.log("This page is reloaded");
  } else {
    console.log("This page is not reloaded");
  }
  setLoading(true);
  let cancel;
  axios
    .get(currentPageUrl, {
      cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
    }).then((res) => {
      setLoading(false);
      setNextpageUrl(res.data.next);
      setPokemons([...pokemons, ...res.data.results])  
    }).catch((e) => {
      setErr(true)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
  request()
}, [currentPageUrl])
```